# node-ytdl-core miniget Error: Status code: 410

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js, ytdl

I'm currently making a `Discord.js` music bot. I use `ytdl-core` to get the video information (ie. `URL`, `title`, `author's name`, `age restriction` etc.). When I get an age restricted video I want to handle it by either bypassing the age restriction somehow (that is a better option) or returning. The problem is that on the first `ytdl` function call for the `ytdl.getInfo()` it gives me an error if the video is age restricted. I'm unable to know if the video is restricted before this function call.

Here's the full error:

```
Error: Status code: 410
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (SOME_PATH\node_modules\miniget\src\index.ts:255:19)   
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:514:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:621:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:487:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:312:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:287:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:226:10)
```

Here's the code (written in `TypeScript`):

```
import {
    AudioPlayerStatus,
    createAudioPlayer,
    createAudioResource,
    joinVoiceChannel,
    StreamType,
} from "@discordjs/voice";
import { Command, Song } from "../../Interfaces";
import ytdl from "ytdl-core";
import { Message, VoiceChannel } from "discord.js";

export const command: Command = {
    name: "play",
    description: "",
    usage: "play",
    category: "Music",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const channel = message.member.voice?.channel;

        if (!channel)
            return message.channel.send(
                "You are not in a voice channel. Please join a voice channel and try again."
            );

        const query = args.join(" ");

        if (ytdl.validateURL(query)) {
            let { age_restricted, author, thumbnails, title, video_url } = (
                await ytdl.getInfo(query)
            ).videoDetails;

            if (age_restricted) return message.reply("Age restricted video");

            let song: Song = {
                title,
                url: video_url,
                thumbnail: thumbnails[thumbnails.length - 1].url,
                author: author.name,
            };

            play(message, <VoiceChannel>channel, song);
        }
    },
};

function play(message: Message, channel: VoiceChannel, song: Song) {
    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    const resource = createAudioResource(
        ytdl(song.url, {
            filter: "audioonly",
            requestOptions: {
                headers: {
                    cookie: "MY_COOKIE" 
                    // Tried for this https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/blob/master/example/cookies.js
                }
            }
        }),
        {
            inputType: StreamType.Arbitrary,
        }
    );

    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: channel.id,
        guildId: message.guild.id,
        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });

    player.play(resource);
    connection.subscribe(player);

    player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => connection.destroy());
}
```